# tab view like button slides up

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have a button that is located on the bottom and when the user taps on it it will slide up to show the menu. How is this possible using code or is there an api or anything that I can use to make this possible in the easiest way? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows a view whose frame is animated when the button is pressed so that either the height of the view, or more likely just the position, is changed so that the view becomes visible. This is a simple `UIView` animation and the view being added so it is hidden behind the button initially.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the iOS documentation for Animating Views https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html 
You should be able to create the view and its content either with the interface builder or in code. Start with the view off the bottom of the screen and then use animateWithDuration:animations: using the frame property.